# MVC C# foreach Loop passing button selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have a listing view which shows the jobs extracted from the database. Each Job has a button next to it. When I move to the next page, i need to carry the specified job, display it and later save it to my database.

This is inside my **Controller class.**
I extracted the jobs in the index and after clicking the button i want to move to the "Apply" method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var jobs = (from Jobs in db.Jobs
              orderby Jobs.Id descending
              select Jobs);
  List<CareersClasses.Jobs> job = jobs.ToList();
  return View(job);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(){
  return View();
}
```

This is The **Index** View:

```
<table>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Jobs", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Desc)
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="Apply" name="Apply" value="@item.Title">Apply</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  }
</table>
```

This is the **Apply** View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Jobs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Applicants</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.JobId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNb)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNb)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNb)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      Curriculum Vitae
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <input type="file" name="file"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobId)
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}
```

I also want to add a document to my database:
I used this method in the "submit" method is it correct?

**Submit Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection formCollection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    CareersClasses.Applicants Applicants = new CareersClasses.Applicants();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        Applicants.FName = formCollection["FName"];
        Applicants.LName = formCollection["LName"];
        Applicants.Email = formCollection["Email"];
        Applicants.Country = formCollection["Country"];
        Applicants.PhoneNb = int.Parse(formCollection["PhoneNb"]);

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            byte[] data = GetDocument(file);

            Applicants.CV = data;
        }

        db.Applicants.Add(Applicants);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ListApps");
    }
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public byte[] GetDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //Get file info
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var contentLength = file.ContentLength;
    var contentType = file.ContentType;

    //Get file data
    byte[] data = new byte[] { };
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    }

    return data;

}
```

**The Classes Model:**

```
public class CareersClasses
    {
        public class Applicants
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FName { get; set; }
            public string LName { get; set; }
            public int PhoneNb { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public byte[] CV { get; set; }

            public int JobId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("JobId")]
            public virtual Jobs Jobs { get; set; }

        }

        public class Jobs
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Desc { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

*Note: I am still new to MVC and I did a lot of research before asking these questions but i'm still lost, so your help will be much appreciated*

Comment: Difficult to understand exactly what your doing here. Your `Index` view should not have `form` elements, just links to an `Apply` method (passing the `JobId` of `Jobs`) which renders a link to a view to edit. What is the model for your Apply (or Submit?) view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put the form elements in the Index view just to save accessing time.. this is just a small project to practice mvc that's why... I will include the models in a second

Comment: @StephenMuecke my steps are:
1-the first page(index) lists the job Titles and description with an apply button for each job title and description combinationr
2-after clicking one of the buttons, the user is moved to the apply page where there's a title noting what job title he/she applied to and a list of textboxes to fill information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Index` view should have links (not forms) to an `Apply()` method for the Job. The link passes the `Id` of the `Jobs` to the method, which initializes a new instance of `CareersClasses` and sets its `JobId` property. The method then returns a view to edit the `CareersClasses` and the submit button posts back the model to the POST method.

Index.cshtml

```
<table>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Desc)</td>
      <td>@Html.ActionLink("Apply", "Apply", new { ID = item.Id})</td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Apply(int ID)
{
  CareersClasses model = new CareersClasses();
  model.JobID = ID;
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Apply(CareersClasses model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  // save the model and redirect
}
```

Apply.cshtml

```
@model CareersClasses
....
@Html.BeginForm())
{
  // controls for properties of CareersClasses
  ....
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```